# Angular: Passing a function to dumb component

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular2-template

I'm writing an AWS security groups module clone with Angular and ngrx. I'm trying to pass a method into the dumb component for creating a new security group.

```js
...

const schemas: any[] = [];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        SecurityGroupsComponent,
        SecurityGroupsTableComponent,
        SecurityGroupsListComponent
    ],
    schemas: schemas,
    exports: [SecurityGroupsComponent]
})

export class SecurityGroupsModule { }
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-security-groups-table',
    templateUrl: './security-groups-table.component.html',
})
export class SecurityGroupsTableComponent  {
    onCreateSecurityGroup() {
        console.log('Create Security Group');
    }

}
```

```html
<app-security-groups-list
    [createSecurityGroup]="onCreateSecurityGroup"></app-security-groups-list>
```

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
    selector: 'app-security-groups-list',
    templateUrl: './security-groups-list.component.html',
})
export class SecurityGroupsListComponent {
    @Input()
    createSecurityGroup: Function;

    selectSecurityGroup(securityGroupId: string) {
        this.securityGroupSelected.next(securityGroupId);
    }

}
```

and when the template is rendered I get this exception:
Can't bind to 'createSecurityGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'app-security-groups-list'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have missed to add `SecurityGroupsListComponent`  to `NgModule`.

Please make sure you do below step before use it:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [SecurityGroupsListComponent]
})
```

Comment: Nope, it is declared correctly in NGModule. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: These snippets are just an abstraction from a giant app. What parts of code do you want to see?

Comment: I added NgModule

Answer (score 0):

```
  export const DECLARATIONS = [SecurityGroupsComponent,
                         SecurityGroupsTableComponent,
                        SecurityGroupsListComponent]
```

and then

```
    declarations: DECLARATIONS,
    schemas: schemas,
    exports: DECLARATIONS
```

Comment: I don't want to export more then one component

Comment: If you're using app-security-groups-list outside of SecurityGroupsModule, you MUST export it.

Comment: I'm not using it outside this module